# Powershell A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '10'. While not even using a positional parameter

Tags: powershell, syntax, parameter-passing, positional-parameter

Note that the example code is contrived and is meant for illustration of the problem only.

I wanted to make a function in powershell to get some random numbers but i'm running into the very weird issue that when i dont use the position defining of the paramater i still get a error about it.

My code is:

```sh
function select-random {

  param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory)]
    [int]$min,
    [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory)]
    [int]$max
  )

  Get-Random $min $max

}
```

The error this script gets with the command: `select-random 5 10`

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '10'.
```

And with the command: `select-random -min 5 -max 10`

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '10'.`
```

The weirdest thing is that the ISE detects the manualy defined paramater in the tab menu.

Is my syntax wrong or is it a powershell bug but mainly how do i fix this?

Comment: You define the parameters as `[int]`, but treat them as strings (`""`)... Also, the `Minimum` parameter is **Named** only, while the first positional parameter should be`Maximum`. Best name both parameters on `Get-Random`

Comment: Read the error message carefully: _**Get-Random** : A positional parameter cannot be found_… Use `get-random -Minimum $min -Maximum $max` at line # 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) and [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) have provided the crucial pointers in the comments on the question:

**You're trying to pass both the `$min` and `$max` arguments *positionally* to [`Get-Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-random), yet `Get-Random` supports only *one* positional argument, namely for the `-Maximum` parameter.**

Thus, **at least the `$min` value must be passed as a *named* argument, i.e. as `-Minimum $min`** for your command to work syntactically. However, for symmetry and readability it is better to pass `$max` as a named argument as well:

```sh
# Use *named* arguments.
Get-Random -Minimum $min -Maximum $max
```

---

**How to determine a command's positional arguments:**

The [about_Command_Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax) conceptual help topic describes the notation used in PowerShell's so-called *syntax diagrams*.

To display the syntax diagrams (only), use `Get-Command -Syntax` (or pass `-?` / use `Get-Help`, which shows additional information):

```sh
PS> & { Get-Command -Syntax $args[0] } Get-Random

Get-Random [[-Maximum] <Object>] [-SetSeed <int>] [-Minimum <Object>] [-Count <int>] [<CommonParameters>]

Get-Random [-InputObject] <Object[]> -Shuffle [-SetSeed <int>] [<CommonParameters>]

Get-Random [-InputObject] <Object[]> [-SetSeed <int>] [-Count <int>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

**Only parameters whose *names alone* are enclosed in `[...]`<sup>[1]</sup> are *positional* - e.g. `[-Maximum]`** - and, if multiple ones are supported, they are listed in the order in which they must be passed on invocation.

Note that each output line represents a separate *parameter set* (see [about_Parameter_Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parameter_Sets)), but since you're passing a minimum and maximum value, only the first one is of interest here:

As you can see, only `-Maximum` is positional in the first parameter set, `-Minimum` and all the other parameters are not.

---

Here's **helper function `Get-PositionalParameter`, which makes it easier to determine a command's positional parameters**:

```sh
Function Get-PositionalParameter {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Outputs a given command's positional parameters, if any.
#>
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [string] $Name
  )
  Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
  # Resolve the name to a cmdlet first, if necessary
  $cmd = (Get-Command $Name)
  if ($cmd.ResolvedCommand) { $cmd = $cmd.ResolvedCommand }

  $cmd.ParameterSets | ForEach-Object {
    if ($posParams = $_.Parameters.Where( { $_.Position -ge 0 })) {
      [pscustomobject] @{
        PositionalParams = $posParams.Name
        ParameterSet     = $_.Name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Applied to `Get-Random`:

```sh
PS> Get-PositionalParameter Get-Random

PositionalParams ParameterSet
---------------- ------------
Maximum          RandomNumberParameterSet
InputObject      ShuffleParameterSet
InputObject      RandomListItemParameterSet
```

Note that the parameter set *names* do not surface in the help topics and when you use `Get-Command -Syntax`, because they aren't really meant for *public* display, but their names are usually descriptive enough to infer their purpose.

---

<sup>[1] Contrast this with the parameter specification *as a whole* being enclosed in `[...]` - e.g. `[-Minimum <Object>]` - which independently indicates that the parameter as a whole is *optional* (not mandatory, i.e. passing an argument is not *required*).</sup>