# What is the technical term for "<somevalue>" this are used in helps of commands

Tags: powershell, console

I was learning power shell and found a video it was explained how to read help then I encountered a technical term but I am not able to spell it or able to find it on the internet. I have attached the video with time for reference
https://youtu.be/UVUd9_k9C6A?t=4255

example
SYNTAX

```
New-Item [-Path] <string[]> [-ItemType <string>] [-Value <Object>] [-Force]
```

// here after the name of a parameter we have some info as like`<string>` what is the technical term for this thing

Answer (score 2):

The `<typename>` / `<typename[]>` notation is **used solely in PowerShell's [syntax diagrams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax), to denote the *data type* ([.NET type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/common-type-system)) of a given parameter**.

- Whether `typename` represents the *simple name* of a .NET type without also including its *namespace* component (e.g. `<string>`) or the *full* type name (e.g. `<System.String>`) varies *situationally*:

  - *Full* (namespace-qualified) type names are only shown if you use `-?` or [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help) and the target command's help information happens to be provided via *separate, MAML-based help files*.

    - Additionally, [`System.Enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Enum)-derived parameters are shown by their *values* rather than their type name.
  - Otherwise - which notably includes written-in-PowerShell functions and scripts using *comment-based help* - you get the *simple* names only.
  - Similarly, you only get the *simple* type names if you use [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) `-Syntax` - irrespective of how the target command's help is implemented.
- **A `typename` followed by `[]`** indicates that a given parameter **accepts an *array*** of instances of the given type - e.g. `<string[]>`.

Note:

- Technically, if only a *simple* type name is displayed, the display is *ambiguous*, as types of a given name may exist in *multiple* namespaces.  That said, in the typical case it'll be clear what types are being referred to, notably with .NET primitive types such as `string`, `int`, ...

  - When in doubt, use reflection to determine the full type name; e.g., to determine the full .NET type name of the `New-Object` cmdlet's `-Property` parameter:

    ```
    (Get-Command New-Object).Parameters['Property'].ParameterType.FullName
    ```
- Given PowerShell's flexible automatic type conversions, a given argument needn't be of the *exact* type declared by the target parameter; it can be any type that PowerShell can *convert to* the target type. This is generally helpful, but can sometimes lead to surprising behavior. Notably, a `<string>` parameter accepts argument of (almost) *any* type, given that any object can be converted to a string, though not always meaningfully - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69653097/45375) for more information.
- For additional information on how to read syntax diagrams, namely with respect to which parameters are *positional* and which ones are *optional*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65617895/45375).

---

Notably, **the `<typename>` syntax-diagram notation *differs* from how types are represented in actual PowerShell *code*, where a type name must be enclosed in `[...]` to form a so-called *type literal* (e.g. `[string]`)**.

Additionally, namespace qualification of `typename` *is* required, *except* if a given type is located *directly* in the `System.` namespace (e.g. `[datetime]` for `System.DateTime`) or if a [type accelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Accelerators) is used (e.g. `[regex]`); if a namespace component must be specified, the `System.` component may be omitted.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66996505/45375) for more information about type literals.