# Powershell.exe: General Question about the Syntax

Tags: windows, powershell

if i am opening powershell via cmd with following syntax:

```
powershell "C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\Myscript.ps1"
```

and this is the syntax:

```
PowerShell[.exe]
    [-PSConsoleFile <file> | -Version <version>]
    [-NoLogo]
    [-NoExit]
    [-Sta]
    [-Mta]
    [-NoProfile]
    [-NonInteractive]
    [-InputFormat {Text | XML}]
    [-OutputFormat {Text | XML}]
    [-WindowStyle <style>]
    [-EncodedCommand <Base64EncodedCommand>]
    [-ConfigurationName <string>]
    [-File - | <filePath> <args>]
    [-ExecutionPolicy <ExecutionPolicy>]
    [-Command - | { <script-block> [-args <arg-array>] }
                | { <string> [<CommandParameters>] } ]

PowerShell[.exe] -Help | -? | /?
```

[microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1)

which paramater am i refering to
is it `"[-PSConsoleFile <file> | -Version <version>]"`?
because in my example i did not specify the parameter with "-" and it is still working!

Comment: it's called a *Positional Parameter*. If the parameter arguments align where the parameters would go, it will work due to it's position. You can recreate it yourself using metadata in a parameter declaration inside a function: `[parameter(Position=0)]`, etc.

Comment: so -command is in position [0] ? if i had to guess i would say -PSconsoleFile is in position [0]

Comment: See mklements answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be inferred from the [syntax diagram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax) you quote from the linked help topic, but **the first *positional* (unnamed) argument you pass to the PowerShell CLI implicitly binds to**:

- `-Command` in `powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell)
- `-File` in `pwsh` (PowerShell (Core) 7+)

(It is unfortunate that the CLI's syntax diagram doesn't contain this information (in *cmdlet* help topics, it does, though it may not be readily obvious - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65617895/45375)); it also doesn't reflect which parameters are *mutually exclusive*, such as `-File` and `-Command`. As of this writing, the information about the positional parameters isn't even in the *description* at [about_PowerShell_exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1), but it is in [about_Pwsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh))

In other words:

```bash
powershell "C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\Myscript.ps1"
```

is the same as:

```bash
powershell -Command "C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\Myscript.ps1"
```

- That is, the script path is passed *positionally* in the first command, i.e. its target parameter isn't explicitly specified the way it is in the second command. Another way of looking at is that the path was passed as an *unnamed* argument.
- Order matters among positional arguments, and the target command must (a) designate each parameter that may be bound positionally as such and (b) specify a number that defines the relative position among all positional arguments. (In PowerShell code, an advanced function or script (cmdlet-like) would express that with a parameter attribute such as `[Parameter(Position=0)]`, as [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) notes) - see the conceptual [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters) help topic).
- In the PowerShell CLI, **special considerations apply to positional arguments**:

  - Any arguments following the `-Command` or `-File` argument are  treated as *pass-through* arguments:

    - With `-File`, they are passed to the specified `.ps1` script.
    - With `-Command`, they form part of the PowerShell source code that is being passed (if multiple arguments are passed, they are individually stripped of syntactic `"` quotes and joined with spaces).
  - Therefore, **`-Command` and `-File` - as well any pass-through arguments - should always be placed *last* on the CLI command line.**

Comment: huh, that is odd 'cause I know I've seen it be `-command` before as the first parameter.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, `-Command` is the implied default for `powershell.exe`, but you may specify it explicitly; am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: thanks for that neat explanation - shouldn't the syntax diagram list the "-command" parameter first to express the position [0]?

sorry if i have asked something obvious now, but that was a little bit complex

Comment: @NoErrorNoCry Yes, the syntax diagram is inadequate  - I've added more details to the answer. For `pwsh` the equivalent help topic now mentions that `-File` is the default, but one you link to, for `powershell.exe`, does _not_ mention that `-Command` is the default.

Comment: @NoErrorNoCry, you could raise an issue at  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues