# How To Capture Output from Non-elevated Process Run from Elevated Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to update an elevated PowerShell script that's using StartProcess on a BAT file that runs RunAs on PowerShell.exe to run another PowerShell script without elevation in order to clone a git repository so that the directory is created in a way that a normal non-elevated user will be able to use.

- Elevated PS1: Start-Process

  - => Elevated .BAT: RunAs /trustlevel:0x20000

    - => Non-elevated PS1

This is failing in some environments and I can't figure out why so I'm trying to figure out how to capture stdout and stderr from all levels of this process, but I'm not seeing the error or any output. I can capture it down to the BAT file level, but I can't seem to see anything that's happening within the inner-most Powershell script.

This seems like an awful lot of work just to programmatically clone a Git repository from an elevated process. Is there a way to make this work or is there an easier way?

**EDIT:** Just learned that this solution was broken as of Windows 11 Update 22H2: https://superuser.com/questions/1749696/parameter-is-incorrect-when-using-runas-with-trustlevel-after-windows-11-22h2
but the workaround is to use the /machine switch when running RunAs.

Comment: How about using a very different, simple and stable approach? Do you have any software deployment, patchmanagement... At least active directory might install the script and update outdated files via gpo. Otherwise try using a scheduled tasks for updating - maybe upon creation with a script that makes self deletion of the task after success....

Comment: What about using Named Pipes? For example create named pipe on child process (**System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream**), redirect StdOut (or put any data) to this named pipe. From parent (privileged) process connect to child's pipe for reading stream.

Comment: @Daemon-5 I see the pipe can skip over the bat and just talk between the outermost PowerShell and the innermost PowerShell. I will add an answer with details. Thanks.

Comment: You said "talk between the outermost PowerShell and the innermost PowerShell." And batch process can use the created pipe too: **echo DATA > \\.\pipe\SAMPipe**

Comment: @Daemon-5 I tried updating runas to direct output with >\\.\pipe\SAMPipe instead of capturing output in test2.ps1 but that just seemed to cause the parent process to hang unable to connect the pipe. Did I miss something?

Comment: I suppose in this case: receiving pipe should have apropriate direction **[System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::In** (or InOut)

Comment: @Daemon-5 That is what I have in test.ps1 where the receiving pipe is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest simplifying your approach as follows:

- Use *synchronous* invocation of `runas.exe`, via [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) `-Wait`, which obviates the need for an intermediate batch file, and the need for a named pipe (`System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream`)
- Let the `runas.exe`-launched PowerShell child process that runs `test2.ps1` capture that script's output in a temporary file, which you can read after the `Start-Process -Wait` call returns.
- `test2.ps1` can then just produce output normally - no need for `System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream`

##### Elevated PowerShell Script (`test.ps1`):

```bash
function IsAdmin{
  $currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
  $Is64 = [Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem
  if ($currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
      Write-Output "Running with elevated privileges. (64-bit=$Is64)"
  } else {
      Write-Output "Running without elevated privileges. (64-bit=$Is64)"
  }
}

IsAdmin

# Create a temporary file in which to capture the output from the 
# PowerShell child process launched by runas.exe.
$outFile = New-TemporaryFile

# Use Start-Process -Wait to directly invoke runas.exe,
# which doesn't just wait for runas.exe ITSELF to exit, but also
# waits for its CHILD processes.
# This ensures that execution is blocked until the other PowerShell script exits too. 
Start-Process -Wait runas.exe @"
/machine:amd64 /trustlevel:0x20000 "powershell -c & \"$PSScriptRoot\test2.ps1\" -drive C:\ *> \"$outFile\""
"@

# Now $outFile contains all output produced by the other PowerShell script.
Write-Verbose -Verbose "Output from the runas.exe-launched PowerShell script:"
Get-Content -LiteralPath $outFile

$outFile | Remove-Item # Clean up.
```

##### Non-Elevated PowerShell Script (`test2.ps1`):

```bash
param([string]$drive)

function IsAdmin{
    $currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
    $Is64 = [Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem
    if ($currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
        Write-Output "Running with elevated privileges. (64-bit=$Is64)"
    } else {
        Write-Output "Running without elevated privileges. (64-bit=$Is64)"
    }
}

function Setup-Test{
    Write-Output "Testing Powershell with Parameter Drive=$drive"
    git config --global user.name
    cd bob
    Write-Error "Error Line 1
Error Line 2"
    Write-Error "Error Line 3"
    $d = 3/0
    Write-Output "Done Testing Powershell"
}

IsAdmin
Setup-Test
```

Comment: @BlueMonkMN, good point: you need *>  I’ve updated the answer.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN, yes, on Windows process command lines (as interpreted by those executables built on the Microsoft C/C++/.NET compilers and those that use the `CommandLineToArgv` WinAPI function) ``\`` only acts as the escape character before `"` (and ``\`` itself, if part of a run followed by `"`) - all other instances are taken literally.

Comment: Wow, I like this solution so much better, and it captured much more of the output too. Two things I don't understand: 1. Why does Get-Content work without the -Path switch? 2. I didn't use the Remove-Item line, but why would you pipe the file name into it instead of passing it as the argument to -Path?

Comment: Glad to hear it, @BlueMonkMN. PowerShell cmdlets (selectively) support _positional_ (unnamed) arguments. The (first) such argument passed to `Get-Content` binds to the `-Path` parameter - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65617895/45375). Piping to `Remove-Item` is more robust, because it binds to the `-LiteralPath` parameter (rather than `-Path`), which prevents inadvertent interpretation of its argument as a _wildcard_ expression; the alternative is to use `Remove-Item -LiteralPath $outFile` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177977/45375).

Comment: P.S., @BlueMonkMN, it follows from the previous comment that `Get-Content -LiteralPath $outFile` should be used for full robustness (I've updated the answer). In practice (at least on Windows), the difference between `-LiteralPath` and `-Path` only matters for paths that contain `[` and `]`, which are metacharacters in PowerShell's [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards).

Comment: What does the ampersand on the runas line accomplish?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN, it is the call operator, which is required for invocation of the script syntactic reasons, namely because the script-file path is quoted - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375).

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with a named pipe.

### Elevated PowerShell Script (test.ps1)

```powershell
function IsAdmin{
    $currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
    $Is64 = [Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem
    if ($currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
        Write-Output "Running with elevated privileges. (64-bit=$Is64)"
    } else {
        Write-Output "Running without elevated privileges. (64-bit=$Is64)"
    }
}

IsAdmin
Write-Output "Running $PSScriptRoot\test.bat"
Start-Process -FilePath "$PSScriptRoot\test.bat" -ArgumentList "C:\" -NoNewWindow
$np = new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream('.','SAMPipe', [System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::In,[System.IO.Pipes.PipeOptions]::None,[System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel]::Impersonation)
$np.Connect()
$sr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($np)
while ($l=$sr.ReadLine()) {
   Write-Output $l
}
$sr.Close()
$np.Close()
```

### BAT file in the middle to de-elevate (test.bat)

```bat
runas /machine:amd64 /trustlevel:0x20000 "powershell -command %~dp0test2.ps1 -drive %1 >dummy.txt"
```

### Non-Elevated PowerShell Script (test2.ps1)

```powershell
param([string]$drive)

function IsAdmin{
    $currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
    $Is64 = [Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem
    if ($currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
        Write-Output "Running with elevated privileges. (64-bit=$Is64)"
    } else {
        Write-Output "Running without elevated privileges. (64-bit=$Is64)"
    }
}

function Setup-Test{
    Write-Output "Testing Powershell with Parameter Drive=$drive"
    git config --global user.name
    cd bob
    Write-Error "Error Line 1
Error Line 2"
    Write-Error "Error Line 3"
    $d = 3/0
    Write-Output "Done Testing Powershell"
}

$np = New-Object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream('SAMPipe',[System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::Out)
$np.WaitForConnection()
$sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($np)
$sw.WriteLine('Begin Non-Elevated Process Pipe')
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    try {
        IsAdmin
        Setup-Test
    } catch {
        Write-Error $_
    } 
} -ErrorVariable errVar -OutVariable out
foreach ($line in $out){
    $sw.WriteLine($line)
}
foreach ($line in $errVar) {
    $sw.WriteLine($line)
}
$sw.WriteLine('End Non-Elevated Process Pipe')
$sw.Close()
$np.Close()
```

### Output

```text
Running with elevated privileges. (64-bit=True)
Running C:\Users\bmarty\source\PowerShellTest\test.bat

C:\Users\bmarty\source\PowerShellTest>runas /machine:amd64 /trustlevel:0x20000 "powershell -command C:\Users\bmarty\source\PowerShellTest\test2.ps1 -drive C:\ >dummy.txt"
Begin Non-Elevated Process Pipe
Running without elevated privileges. (64-bit=True)
Testing Powershell with Parameter Drive=C:\
Ben Marty
Cannot find path 'C:\Users\bmarty\source\PowerShellTest\bob' because it does not exist.
Error Line 1
Error Line 2
Error Line 3
Attempted to divide by zero.
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Attempted to divide by zero. ---> System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
Attempted to divide by zero.
Attempted to divide by zero.
End Non-Elevated Process Pipe
Done running
```

I don't understand why the output of git config only appears in the output if I include >dummy.txt in the BAT file.

Answer (score 0):

Try working with ACLs instead. You can set that up on the parent directory so you don't even need to run the script in an elevated context.

Just set up a "gitclone" account that can write into the repository parent directory and then add the rest of the users as read+execute.

The rest will come automagically through inheritance.

Then run script as that "gitclone" user.

Comment: The main process needs to run elevated because it also installs Git and a whole bunch of other software.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN admin privileges are not necessary for GIT - and im guessing they never were. Anything which requires admin privileges automatically is suspicious unless its a cryptographically signed binary from trusted sources. _(and of course your trust root has to be reliable, too)_

Comment: @specializt The process is also installing MS SQL Server and other system services.