# How to pass uninstallation password to remote system via powershell to uninstall an application which is password Protected

Tags: powershell, passwords, uninstallation, invoke, protected

I can silently uninstall application which doesn't have password Protected using Powershell .

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $uninstall32 /SILENT
```

For password protected application (Setup created using Inno SetUp ) it popup for asking password. Is there an option to pass password without popup?

If it succeeds I want to remotely uninstall password protected application

Without password protected application remotely I had uninstalled silently.

I tried

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $uninstall32 UNINSTALL_PASSWORD =AR /SILENT
```

Comment: You tried with `UNINSTALL_PASSWORD =AR` in the argument list, and then what? What happens? Does it exit with an error? Does it ignore the argument and prompt you for the password?

Comment: Thank you Mathias for the suggestion . When i tried with this  start-process -Wait -FilePath $uninstall32  -ArgumentList UNINSTALL_PASSWORD=AR it pop for Password. A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/SILENT'. message coming if i add /SILENT after -ArgumentList UNINSTALL_PASSWORD=AR

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

Specify the pass-through arguments *as a single string*:

```bash
# Note: Parameters -FilePath and -ArgumentList are positionally implied.
Start-Process -Wait $uninstall32 'UNINSTALL_PASSWORD=AR /SILENT'
```

If you need to embed *variable references* or *expressions* in the arguments string, use `"..."` quoting, i.e. an [expandable (double-quoted) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) , rather than `'...'`, a [verbatim (single-quoted) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) .

---

When you use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process), any arguments to be passed to the target executable (`-FilePath`) must be specified via the `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) parameter, to which you must pass a *single* value.

- Note: While `-ArgumentList` technically accepts an *array* of string values,<sup>[1]</sup> allowing you to specify the pass-through arguments *individually*, separated with `,`  a [long-standing bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576) unfortunately makes it better to encode all arguments in a *single string*, because it makes the situational need for *embedded* double-quoting explicit - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71271756/45375).

Both parameters can be bound *positionally*, meaning that values need not be prefixed with the target parameter names.

- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65617895/45375) for how to identify a command's positional parameters via its [syntax diagram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax).

Therefore, **your attempt**:

```bash
# !! BROKEN
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $uninstall32 UNINSTALL_PASSWORD =AR /SILENT
```

is equivalent to:

```bash
# !! BROKEN
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $uninstall32 -ArgumentList UNINSTALL_PASSWORD =AR /SILENT
```

and also equivalent to, using positional parameter binding for both `-FilePath` and `-ArgumentList`:

```bash
# !! BROKEN
Start-Process -Wait $uninstall32 UNINSTALL_PASSWORD =AR /SILENT
```

That is, `UNINSTALL_PASSWORD` *alone* was bound to `-ArgumentList`, whereas `=AR` and `/SILENT` are additional, positional arguments that cause a *syntax error*, because both parameters that support positional binding - `-FilePath` and `-ArgumentList` - are *already bound*.

---

<sup>[1] From PowerShell's perspective, even an array of values (`,`-separated values) is a *single* argument.</sup>