# Trying to get a command to run in cli from a powershell script but it is picking up an "ambiguous" parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise, start-process

I am currently trying to get a command that I know works in CLI to run through a PowerShell Ise script but it will not allow me to run it as it is picking up a part of the command as a parameter.

I tried to run the following command, but it brings up an error:

```
Start-Process ssh -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 Username@IP
```

```
Start-Process : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'o' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -OutVariable -OutBuffer.
At line:1 char:30
+ Start-Process ssh -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group14- ...
+                              ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

What is supposed to happen is the cli should pop up and allow me to access a switch which as i have stated earlier works when I manually input it into Cli.

Comment: Change from `Start-Process ssh args go here` to `Start-Process ssh "args go here"`

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

As [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) notes, you must *quote* the list of arguments to pass through to `ssh`:

```
# Note the '...' around the entire list of pass-through arguments.
# Use "..." if you need string interpolation.
# Use *embedded* "..." quoting for arguments that contain spaces, for instance.
Start-Process ssh '-o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 Username@IP'
```

---

There are two problems with your approach:

- **Because `-o` is *unquoted*, [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) interprets it as one of *its* parameter names**.

  - Thus, *pass-through* arguments that happen to look like PowerShell parameters, must be *quoted*, e.g. - *if* passed individually (which isn't advisable; see next point) - `'-o'`.
  - As for the **error** you saw:

    - PowerShell's "elastic syntax" allows you to use parameter-name *prefixes* for brevity, so you don't have to type / tab-complete the full parameter name.
    - However, such a prefix must be *unambiguous*; if it isn't, PowerShell complains and lists the *candidate* parameter names, such as `-OutVariable` and `-OutBuffer` for `-o` in this case. Thus, prefix `-outv` would have avoided the ambiguity, for instance. Also note that some parameters have unambiguous short *aliases*, such as `-ov` for `-OutVariable`.
- More fundamentally, **trying to pass multiple pass-through arguments *individually* to `Start-Process` causes a *syntax error***:

  - It is **best to specify all pass-through arguments as a single, quoted string, using embedded *double*-quoting, if necessary.**

    - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76713933/45375) explains the syntax problem in detail, but the short of it is that `Start-Process` expects pass-through arguments via a *single* argument, passed to its `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) parameter, which is the 2nd *positional* parameter.
    - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375) explains why - even though you can specify the pass-through arguments individually as the elements of an *array* (`,`-separated), a long-standing bug makes the single-string approach preferable.