# How to use Start-Process and msiexec to install from a .msi file?

Tags: powershell

I have a folder that has many .msi files, and I want to install them one by one in an automated Powershell script. I've been failing to so far. I'm running with elevated privilages (admin). First I set the folder to be $softwarePath. Then, I specify each .msi like "$softwarePath\msi01.msi".

```
$softwarePath = "C:\folder1\folder2"

# Installing msi1
$ODBC17 = "$softwarePath\msi01.msi"
```

I can get 3 behaviors/errors.

1. If the execution line is below, I get

   ```
    Start-Process msiexec -argumentlist /i $ODBC17 -wait
    ## OR with double quotes
    Start-Process msiexec -argumentlist /i "$ODBC17" -wait

    returning Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\folder1\folder2\msi01.msi'.
   ```
2. If I use a single quote like below, a red error pops up saying "the installation package could not be opened. Verify that the pachage exists and that you can access it..."

   ```
    Start-Process msiexec -argumentlist '/i $ODBC17' -wait
    ## OR with double quotes
    Start-Process msiexec -argumentlist '/i "$ODBC17"' -wait
   ```
3. If I don't use Start-Process, there won't be any error. I will see a windows installer but it never actually executes the installation.

   ```
    msiexec /i $ODBC17 -wait
    ## using single quotes, double quotes, or combinations does not make any difference
   ```

[image: windows Installer]

What I eventually wanted is:[image: the setup widget]

Comment: `Start-Process msiexec -ArgumentList '/i',$ODBC17 -Wait`

Comment: Preferably: ``Start-Process msiexec -ArgumentList "/i `"$ODBC17`"" -Wait``

Comment: [`Start-Process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)'s `-ArgumentList` parameter is technically _array_-typed, requiring individual arguments to be passed `,`-separated; however, an unfortunate, [long-standing bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576) makes it better to encode all arguments in a _single string_, because it makes the situational need for _embedded_ double-quoting explicit - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76713933/45375) and the linked duplicate.

Comment: Alternative without `Start-Process`: Given that `msiexec` executes _asynchronously_ in PowerShell, even in scripts,  a trick is needed to make it execute synchronously: pipe to `Write-Output`: `msiexec /i $ODBC17 | Write-Output`. If the command involves properties whose values require quoting, call via `cmd /c`, e.g. `cmd /c 'msiexec /i some.msi PROP="quoted value"'`.  Either way, the process exit code will be reflected in `$LASTEXITCODE` afterwards.
See the second linked duplicate for details.

Comment: or in ps 5.1 `install-package $ODBC17`